# Netcat works but SSH does not

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to connect to my ssh server. When I do I get the usual error:

```
Could not resolve hostname x.x.x.x:22: Name or service not known
```

But when I run `nc -v x.x.x.x 22` I get:

```
Connection to x.x.x.x 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1
```

I'm not sure what the next step of how to troubleshoot this would be. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using the command `ssh x.x.x.x:22`? You cannot specify a port for `ssh` like that.

Comment: @jscott alas, thx -- I didn't know this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not show what command you are using to connect via SSH

It looks like you did this

```
$ ssh 192.168.1.1:22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.168.1.1:22: Name or service not known
```

The syntax would be

```
ssh ip -p port
```

Example

```
$ ssh 192.168.1.1 -p 22
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is    SHA256:fPvLlf+BPZHq47Y1GF67YofaAn1jYLElis0.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Though, port 22 is the default SSH port and you should not need to specify it at all.